# ORACLE Client connection error

Tags: oracle

I'm facing an error when I try to connect to ORACLE server.

I download instant client 12c, which contains basic, sdk, tool, and sqlplus.
Now I have the following directories and files.
[image]

And my envrionment variables are like

```
## ORACLE Environment
export ORACLE_SID=TEST01
export ORACLE_HOME=${HOME}/instantclient_12_1
export TNS_ADMIN=${HOME}/instantclient_12_1
export PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}:${PATH}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${ORACLE_HOME}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

When I downloaded the client, there was no "tnsnames.ora" file. So, I created it by myself in the "TNS_ADMIN" path.
The configuration is such as following.

```
TEST01 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.xxx.xxx)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = test01)
    )
  )
```

I checked the HOST value is the server IP address, and port as well.
However, when I boot and try to connect to server via sqlplus, it shows like following.

```
ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

In the server, it connects very well.. I've tried several solutions from Google, but it won't work..

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a RAC database? 99% of the `ORA-12545` errors I have seen were caused by the lack of name resolution of the VIP addresses on the client.

Comment: No, it's not RAC. The thing I can't figure out is another account is using full client and it can connect to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, but I don't understand the reason.

When I connect to the server from the machine the server is installed on, I can use both following commands:

```
1. sqlplus server01/server01
2. sqlplus server01/server01@SID
```

However, from the machine the client is installed on, I can't use the command without `@SID`.
Both envrionments have the same `ORACLE_SID` environment variable and I specify the `SID` in `"tnsnames.ora"`.

Could you explain why it works only with `@SID`?

Thank you.

Comment: `sqlplus server01/server01` initiates a local connection to a database running on the local machine (unless `TWO_TASK` is set), but you tried to connect from another machine.

Comment: It sounds like Server side connections are going through memory (`IPC` I think is the name).  This would indicate that your Listener may not be listening for connections on the external ports.

Comment: I tested the case that Balazs let me know in both environments and you are right. Thank you.